# Does Alembic has an option to run full migration in each version?

Tags: python, migration, alembic

Consider that I have 3 version files in alembic

version1.py  - (holds create tables)
version2.py - (holds alter column name for the already created tables)
version3.py - (add a new column)

In a fresh installation, Is there an option in alembic to run the create table(with altered column name), and the new column in one go ..ie.. in one run?

It should not run version1, then version2 and then version3. Instead each version file should have some option to run the entire schema creation in one go in a fresh installation

For eg: In my case, running version3 in an already deployed product, should add the new column. And if alembic upgrade on version 3 is ran in a fresh installation, it should run only one create statement with the altered column name and the new column